# edgetransport.exe causes heavy read/ write access on hard disk

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, exchange-2010, windows-sbs-2011

I'm running a Windows SBS 2011 Server.

The problem is the edgetransport.exe process, which causes heavy traffic on the hard disk.

I can't locate the error. I changed the disks and hope the problem will be done, but it doesn't help.

[here is one error which I located in a report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ka6X.png)
But I take the solution what is suggested. There is no influence to the edgetransport.exe

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I use the microsoft pop-connector deliverd with SBS2011. One of the mail accounts doesn't work right. The pop connector doesn't fetch the mails and the crowd grows...

In my opinion it isn't a Problem for the SBS Serevr, because the mails just won't be fetched. After I start a pop download on a client, and the pop connector runs fine again on all accounts, the problem was solved and the server runs fine.